# iOS 8.1 Swift Dictionary Error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (XCode 6.1)

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access, ios8.1, swift-dictionary

TLDR: I'm getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error using swift in XCode 6.1 building for iOS8.1. I believe the issue is likely a compiler error.

I am making an app wherein the user is allowed to add (Korean) words from a dictionary (in the English sense) to a word list. I have the following classes that define a word (with associated definitions, audio files, user-interaction statistics, etc.) and a word list (with an associated list of words and methods to add/remove words to the list, alphabetize the list, etc):

```
class Word: NSObject, NSCoding, Printable {
    var hangul = String("")
    var definition = String("")
    // ...
}

class WordList: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var title = ""
    var knownWords = Dictionary<String,String> ()
    // ...

    func addWordToList(wordName: String, wordDefinition: String) {
        // Debug statements
        println("I am WordList \"\(self.title)\" and have the following knownWords (\(self.knownWords.count) words total): ")
        for (_wordName,_wordDefinition) in self.knownWords {
            println("\t\"\(_wordName)\" : \(_wordDefinition)")
        }
        println("\nI am about to attempt to add the word \"\(wordName)\" with definition \"\(wordDefinition)\" to the above dictionary")

        // Add word to wordList, including the 'let' fix 
        fix_EXC_BAD_ACCESS_bug()
        knownWords[wordName] = wordDefinition // EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    }
    func fix_EXC_BAD_ACCESS_bug() {
        // This empty line attempts to solve a exc_bad_access compiler bug when adding a new value to a WordList dictionary
        let newDic = self.knownWords
    }
    // ...
}
```

Next I have a UITableViewController with a UISearchBar that I use to display the dictionary (again in the English sense) of words to the user. The user adds words by tapping a button (which is displaying an image) on the right of each cell, which calls the *@IBAction func addWord()* in the viewController:

```
class AddingWordsToWordList_TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {
    var koreanDictionary = KoreanDictionary() // Custom class with method 'getWord(index: Int)' to return desired Word
    var filteredSearch = [Word]()        
    // ...

    // Add word
    @IBAction func addWord(sender: UIButton) {
        // Add word
        if self.resultSearchController.active {
            let word = filteredSearch[sender.tag]
            wordList.addWordToList(word.hangul, definition: word.definition) // Enter addWordToList() here

        } else {
            let word = koreanDictionary.getWord(sender.tag)
            wordList.addWordToList(word.hangul, definition: word.definition)
        }

        // Set image to gray
        sender.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "add133 gray")

        // Save results
        wordList.save()

        // Reload table data
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    // ...
```

At first the app compiles and seems to run fine. I can add a new word list and start adding words to it, until I add the 8th word. I (always on the 8th word) get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in (WordList) *addWordToList* with the following println information:

```
I am WordList "School" and have the following knownWords (7 words total): 
"방학" : school vacation
"대학원" : graduate school
"학년" : school year
"고등학생" : high school student
"초등학교" : elementary school
"학생" : student
"학교" : school

I am about to attempt to add the word "대학생" with definition "college student" to the above dictionary
```

Note that the order in which I add the words appears irrelevant (i.e. the word "college student" can be added successfully if it is one of the first 7 words). There is nowhere in the code where I explicitly change behavior based on the number of words in a word list (except to display the words in a word list as cells in a UITableView), or any dependencies that would (to my knowledge) make the 8th word a special number. And indeed this number can change by using the *let hack=* solution (see below) to a different number, but for a particular build is *always* the same number.

At this point I'm at a complete loss of what to do. I'm relatively new to swift and have spent quite a few hours looking up how to fix exc_bad_access errors. I've come to the following point:

It seems exc_bad_access errors usually mean one of three things (http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access/)

1. An object is not initialized
2. An object is already released
3. Something else that is not very likely to happen

I don't feel like either 1 or 2 can be the case for me, as right before we get the access error we can print out the contents of the dictionary in question (*knownWords*). However, as is always the case it is highly likely I'm missing something obvious, so please let me know if this is indeed true.

If the error is caused by 3 above ("something else") I have tried the following:

(From [EXC_BAD_ACCESS on iOS 8.1 with Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26809986/exc-bad-access-on-ios-8-1-with-dictionary) and [EXC_BAD_ACCESS when updating Swift dictionary after using it for evaluate NSExpression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26787070/exc-bad-access-when-updating-swift-dictionary-after-using-it-for-evaluate-nsexpr) solutions)

1. I have tried different variations of the *let stupidHack =* scenario, and it does sometimes change the results, but only the number of entries allowed before crashing (i.e. I can sometimes get to the ~15th/16th entry in the dictionary before the error). I have not been able to find an actual, bug-free solution using this method, however.
2. I have rebuilt using both Release and Debug modes; the error appears in both. Note I am only using the simulator and do not have a developer's license to try it on an actual device.
3. I have turned off (set to "None") compiler optimization (it was already off for the Debug build anyway).
4. I have tried building to iOS 8.0 with the same error results.

Any way to get around this issue is appreciated. A *let hack =* solution is acceptable, but preferably a solution will at least guarantee to not produce the error in the future under different build conditions.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you are trying to associate your `knownWords[wordName]` dictionary as a `string`, which won't work. `knownWords[wordName] = wordDefinition` - wordDefinition is a string, so if you want to add that to the dictionary you'll have to go about it differently.

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure what you mean. Apple's documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) lists the following example: 
    var airports: [String: String] = ["YYZ": "Toronto Pearson", "DUB": "Dublin"]
and then modifies the dictionary using airports["LHR"] = "London Heathrow". I'm trying to use the dictionary knownWords in the same way, where the word (i.e. 'hangul') is matched to its definition.

Comment: Right, so when you use `[wordName]` (as a variable) is the value actually a key that already exists?

Comment: Not yet, wordName is a String passed into addWordToList as the key to the key-value pair (wordName, wordDefinition) I am attempting to add to the dictionary knownWords. Note that the code does run and appears to work fine the first 7 times the code is run through, but crashes on the 8th time through.

Comment: There are far better tutorials on properly debugging your app; the only thing that is worth paying attention to on that link is enabling zombies, and setting breakpoints, but a good starting point perhaps. This is much better probably and mentions some key things that should help : http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: One more suggestion: your code is not that complex yet, so converting it to `objective-c` to see if you encounter similar behavior might save you time and possibly answer your question of whether it's your code or xcode. cheers!~